# How to remove exactly the div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to remove exactly the div onclick, not in sequence. I've tried so many ways to fix it, but unfortunately it didn't work.I don't know what to do. So when I click on the div, it removes the div in sequence, but I need to remove exacty the div that Ii was clicking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            color: white;
        }
        div:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="result"></div>

    <script>
        var letters = ['O', 'T', 'V', 'I', 'M', 'N', 'I', 'O', 'A', 'T']


var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main')
var result = document.getElementsByClassName('result')
console.log(main[0]);
main[0].style.display = 'flex'
result[0].style.display = 'flex'
function rand_color() {
    var color = '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6)
    return color;
}


for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

    var div1 = document.createElement('div')
    div1.style.margin = "30px"
    div1.style.fontSize = "60px"
    div1.style.height = "70px"
    div1.style.backgroundColor = rand_color();
    div1.style.width = "80px"
    div1.style.textAlign = "center"
    div1.innerText = letters[i]
    main[0].appendChild(div1)
    div1.onclick = function () {
        main[0].removeChild(main[0].childNodes[0]); `What should I write instead of CHILDNODES[0]`
        var div2 = document.createElement('div')
        div2.innerHTML = this.innerText
        div2.style.margin = "30px"
        div2.style.fontSize = "60px"
        div2.style.height = "70px"
        div2.style.backgroundColor = rand_color()
        div2.style.width = "80px"
        div2.style.textAlign = "center"
        result[0].appendChild(div2)
        div2.ondblclick = function () {
            result[0].removeChild(div2)
            main[0].appendChild(div2)
        }
    }
}

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the issue is.

Comment: Can you try my code please? When you clicking on the div it will be removed, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `main[0].removeChild(main[0].childNodes[0]); // What should I write instead of CHILDNODES[0]`

```js
main[0].removeChild(this) // this refers to the clicked element
```

EDIT:

As the indices suggest, `main[0].removeChild(main[0].childNodes[0]);` removes the first element (with index 0).

If the element is clicked, it is `this` inside the `onclick` function, so you have direct reference to it. A more general approach would be:

```js
div1.onclick = function () {
   this.parentElement.removeChild(this)
   ...
}
```

or (if you don't mind it does not work in Internet Explorer) you can directly [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) the `this` element, which is even more elegant and readable:

```js
div1.onclick = function () {
   this.remove()
   ...
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, a short explanation will approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the event listener then reference the event target like this:

```
   for (var x = 0; x < document.getElementsByTagName('div').length; x++) { 
     document.getElementsByTagName('div')[x].addEventListener('click', event => { 
       console.log(event.target, ' was clicked') 
     }); 
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div1.onclick = function (e) {
     e.target.remove()
}
```

Comment: add some explanation how your answer solves the OP's problem

Comment: Actually, if you took the time to read the question, its basically "`What should I write instead of CHILDNODES[0]`", and its what I answered, no ?